# Why HashMap Takes capacity as capacity <<= 1;

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to know why `HashMap` always takes a size which is multiple of 2 and why other collections do not?

What is the reason behind that?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

In fact, all the time the load of your HashMap go more than 75%, a HashMap is created with a double size. This is the reason why hashmap size is always a power of two.
You might be interested by this article :
http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal

Comment: Then why this is not for other collections(Like hashtable etc) whose size got doubled when load factor passes.

Comment: In fact it the same, it just that for default initial size of HashMap is already a power of two so you get size = (2^DepSize)*2^(something)  = 2^(K). But you can specify the initial size, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html. So even for a HashMap you can have a size that is not a power of two, but it will always be something like K*2^something.

Comment: Sorry Luc but my question is that there are other collections whose size when passed load factor got doubled but they does'nt use capacity in power of 2 alwayz like hashmap?

Comment: Hey Luc! finally got it. Tnx

Comment: `HashMap` actually does some math internally to use the smallest power-of-two capacity that's larger than the desired capacity. So you'll actually always have a power-of-two capacity